# Running Plans on Puppet Enterprise

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I'm using AWS Opswork for Puppet Enterprise and a git control-repo to manage the puppet code.

I created some tasks on

- control-repo/site/mymodule/tasks

And I can run them from Puppet Enterprise UI (Run / Task menu)

But I can't run plans. I created a plan to run several tasks following [official documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/writing_plans.html#concept-7890) on

- control-repo/site/mymodule/plans
  `plan mymodule::myplan(TargetSpec $nodes) {
      run_task('mymodule::myTask', $nodes)
      run_task('mymodule::myTask2', $nodes)
  }`

The plans doesn't appears on Puppet Enterprise UI. Has anyone managed to execute a plan from Puppet Enterprise? Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Plans are not yet supported in the pe-console. I think they are on the roadmap though. You need to use the CLI for plans currently.